# Update Azure SQL Managed Instance sql account in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, sql

I completed setting up SharePoint 2019 using Azure SQL MI, as you would know MI does not accept service account and have to connect to SharePoint using a local sql account. Now the issue I'm facing is the sql account expired, and when I update the pw in sql it takes central administration down. So I need to find a way to update the password in SharePoint too. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use following powershell to update SharePoint service account password:

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -identity "AzureAD\SA_ManagedAccount" -NewPassword (ConvertTo-Securestring "password-2" -AsPlainText -Force) –SetNewPassword
```

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/update-managed-accounts-password-in-sharepoint-2016-using-ui-and-powershell/

Comment: Hi Julie, The sql account is not a managed account, thus not able to change it thru the script or under managed accounts. As you know you can connect to SQL MI only thru a local sql account. The MS documentation does not mention anything about how we can change the sql account password. I wanted to change the sql account password in the SharePoint server.